# Intercept Activity onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment, android-menu

The user tries to navigate from the current activity using the ActionBar.
He touches one of the icons in the ActionBar and

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

is called.
There are situations that I would like to display a fragment dialog with Yes/No/Cancel
and ask the user if he would like to complete the 'action' of the current activity (sending a message to someone)
Yes = send the message and navigate to the activity that was selected in the ActionBar
No = navigate to the activity that was selected in the ActionBar
Cancel = stay here, dont send the message and dont navigate to the other activity

How can I accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would do an if statement ( (s) to the word statement if you need to use more than 1) and if that code is executed, write what code you want it do along with an else statement if is is not executed. Hope that helps! :) -Ryan Csuha

Answer (score 0):

Or try adapting java.util.Scanner to try to do what you want it to do but I think this can be solved by simple old school if statements.

Comment: I am sorry. I cant understand how the Scanner can help here.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a thought on maybe adapt the scanner to do what you need but I think just a simple if statement(s) should do what you want it to do.